# Eclipse+gtest compile c++ error:multiple definition of test

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I have project like this:
[image]
When I try to compile this,get error:undefined reference to `Foo::Foo()'

I have compiled gtest 1.7 and gmock 1.7,and copied all libg* to /user/lib,and my build setting like this:
  [image]

[image]

and project paths and symbols like this:
[image]

Update:
got a new error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

undefined reference is a linker error, indicating the linker could not find implementation for the specific method.

try to add a implementation for you foo constructor in foo.h

Change:

```
virtual ~Foo();
Foo();
bool foo(void) { return true; }
```

To

```
virtual ~Foo();
Foo() {} //add default implementation
bool foo(void) { return true; }
```

Comment: Thanks,but it is  bool foo(void) { return true; } not foo();

Comment: sorry, misspelled my comment with lower case foo. edited for clarification

Comment: Thanks,I also changed virtual ~Foo(); to ~Foo(){};,but right now got another error:"multiple definition" like updates.